# Unable to create EmailSendDefinition using Postman request

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api

While creating EmailSendDefinition using SOAP request, this error is thrown

Exception occurred during [CreateEmailSendDefinition] ErrorID = 1859226036

The error ID keeps on changing and there is no way to track the ErrorID

My Soap request is similar to the one mentioned in this link 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_email_send_definition_using_the_web_service_api.htm

Comment: The Error Code is 2 with this exception

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution

While sending the SOAP request to create EmailSendDefiniton, we need to mention which Email we want to use.

in the section

`<Email> </Email>`

inside this block mention the `<CustomerKey>` of the Email you want to include not it's `<ID>` 
In most places the examples to create EmailSendDefinition includes `<ID>`
because of which the error is thrown.

Comment: I found that ID works if you're trying to send a 'Classic' email but fails when sending a 'Content Builder' email.